# Dell 4048 - Metro Ethernet Topology?

Tags: ethernet, stacking

I have a customer with 3 sites, 5000 users.  2 sites are Data Centers and 1 site is HQ.  The sites are connected via ring topology with 10G MetroEthernet service - that's 6 10G ports in all across 6 Dell 4048 switches - 2 switches per site.

My idea is to [stack these 6 as a single logical switch](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/force10-s4048-on/S4048-ON-9.10.0.0-Config-Pub/Supported-Stacking-Topologies?guid=GUID-89B3321F-92F6-4AE5-A84B-74E8756B0040&lang=en-us) vs configuring them as standalone switches running VLT between the pair at each location.  I do not see any reason why I would not simply stack them as one switch.

Anyone have a good reason not to stack these Dell 4048's into 1 logical switch?  What's a better topology and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacking makes for a single control plane and an outage of the entire stack during software upgrades.  Therefore, a single stack is not advisable.  For a ring topology, Dell has [Force10 Resilient Ring Protocol (FRRP)](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/force10-s4048-on/S4048_ON_9.9.0.0_Config_Pub-v1/Force10-Resilient-Ring-Protocol-(FRRP)?guid=GUID-28D908FC-E158-403A-819A-6B8ADF0D7B0A&lang=en-us).